# Detecting/Setting the current volume

Tags: java, android, volume

I have an app that will be playing some music sounds. I want the user to be able to use a `SeekBar` to set the volume. So what I need to know is how I can:

1. Check the current volume when the app opens.
2. How to set the volume from within the app.

I know you can detect *what state* the volume is in, but I need more than th

```
AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
switch( audio.getRingerMode() ){
case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
   break;
case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
   break;
case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
   break;
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: why do you wanna do this when the android system is already handling the volume?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the android developer reference itself. See below the methods (getter and setter for volume) from the **AudioManager** class:

```
public int getStreamVolume (int streamType)

Added in API level 1
Returns the current volume index for a particular stream.

Parameters
streamType  The stream type whose volume index is returned.

Returns
The current volume index for the stream.

See Also
getStreamMaxVolume(int)
setStreamVolume(int, int, int)
```